# Filtering out entries in a column that contain UTF-8 arabic characters in R

Tags: r, regex, utf-8

I have a data set called event_table that has a column titled "c.Comments" which contains strings mostly in english, but has some arabic in some of the comment entries. I want to filter out rows in which the comments entry contains arabic characters.

I read the data into R from an xlsx file and the arabic characters show as UTF-8 "< U+4903 >< U+483d >" (with no spaces) etc.

I've tried using regular expressions to achieve what I want, but the strings I'm trying to match refuse to be filtered out. I've tried all kinds of different regular expressions, but none of them seem to do the trick. I'll try filtering out literally "

```
event_table <- event_table %>%
    filter(!grepl("<U+", c.Comments, fixed = TRUE))

event_table <- event_table %>%
    filter(!grepl("<U\\+", c.Comments)
```

"\x", "\d\d\d\d", and all sorts of other combinations have done nothing for me

I'm starting to suspect that my method of filtering may be the issue rather than the regular expression, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what regex engine does grepl use, and what are the string escaping rules of r ?

Comment: "<U?" didn't work. none of the characters in question (<U+xxxx>) seem to be subject to any of my expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arabic chars can be detected with `grep`/`grepl` using a PCRE regex like `\p{Arabic}`:

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c("123", "abc", "ﺏ"))
> df
         x
1      123
2      abc
3 <U+FE8F>
> grepl("\\p{Arabic}", df$x, perl=TRUE)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

In your case, the code will look like

```
event_table <- event_table %>%
    filter(!grepl("\\p{Arabic}", c.Comments, perl=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `?Syntax` help page. The Unicode character associated with  may vary with the assumed codepage. On my machine the R character would be created with the string: "\u4903" but it prints as a Chinese glyph. The regex engine in R (as documented in the `?regex` help page which you should refer to now) is PCRE.

The pattern in this grepl expression will filter out the printing non-ASCII characters:

```
grepl("[[:alnum:]]|[[:punct:]]", "\u4903")
[1] FALSE
```

And I don't think you should be negating that `grepl` result:

```
dplyr::filter(data.frame("\u4903"), grepl("[[:alnum:]]|[[:punct:]]", "\u4903"))
[1] X.䤃.
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
dplyr::filter(data.frame("\u4903"), !grepl("[[:alnum:]]|[[:punct:]]", "\u4903"))
  X.䤃.
1    䤃
```

Comment: This is helpful and partially helps, but my problem is that some entries contain arabic characters in UTF-8 and also normal ASCII characters and scattered punctuation, so I'd like to exclude any entry that contains any UTF-8 characters rather than selecting normal characters

Comment: I was able to achieve what I wanted with:

    event_table <- event_table %>%
        filter(!grepl("[\u0600-\u06FF]", c.Comments)

Comment: @hashtagyoloswag Then you should have marked this question as answered.